# How can I create a hyperlink from a JSON value?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, hyperlink

I am using jQuery, AJAX and JSON to build an unordered list of links. Essentially it's a navigation menu. The name of each link and its URL are both values within the JSON file: `name` and `html_url` respectively.

I have already written the code that creates the basic list (see below), but I now need to make each list item a hyperlink that corresponds to its own particular URL value.

Can someone please advise how I pull the URL value for each item in the JSON file and apply it to my code so that each list item becomes a hyperlink that loads the appropriate URL? Thanks in advance for feedback.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://myurl.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: 'false',
  success: function(data) {
    $(data.categories).each(function(index, value) {
      $('#testnav').append($("<ul>").append($("<li class='cat'>").append(value.name)))
    });
  }
});
```

Sample JSON data is below:

```
categories  
0   
id  360002246652
html_url    "https://sampleurl0"
position    0
created_at  "2019-10-18T17:42:11Z"
updated_at  "2020-02-28T04:37:01Z"
name    "Getting Started"
description ""
locale  "en-us"
source_locale   "en-us"
outdated    false

1   
id  360002246672
html_url    "https://sampleurl1"
position    1
created_at  "2019-10-18T17:42:35Z"
updated_at  "2020-02-06T17:40:43Z"
name    "API Reference"
description ""
locale  "en-us"
source_locale   "en-us"
outdated    false

2   
id  360002254991
url
html_url    "https://sampleurl2"
position    2
created_at  "2019-10-18T17:43:12Z"
updated_at  "2020-03-10T19:09:56Z"
name    "API Reference 2"
description ""
locale  "en-us"
source_locale   "en-us"
outdated    false

3   
id  360002255011
html_url    "https://sampleurl3"
position    3
created_at  "2019-10-18T17:43:50Z"
updated_at  "2019-10-24T21:34:24Z"
name    "Agent UI"
description ""
locale  "en-us"
source_locale   "en-us"
outdated    false
```

Comment: For starters you're appending a new list (`ul`) element for each data item. I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be best to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example To this, you should consider adding an example of your JSON data for testing with.

Answer (score 0):

Append the list outside your loop, then just concatenate the url and name values in each list item:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#testnav').append($('<ul id="navMenu"></ul>'));

    $(data.categories).each(function(index, value) {
        $('#navMenu').append(
            $('<li class="cat"><a href="' + value.url + '"> + value.name + '</a></li>')
        );
    });
}
```

Protip: Single quotes for JS, double for HTML. Saves a lot of hassle and escaping.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need to wrap the content of the `li` in an `a` element, whose `href` is set to the URL from the object in the JSON response. Try this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://myurl.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: 'false',
  success: function(data) {
    let $ul = $('<ul />');
    let html = data.categories.map(c => `<li class="cat"><a href="${c.html_url}">${c.name}</a></li>`);
    $ul.append(html).appendTo('#testnav');
  }
});
```

Comment: Rory. Thank you very much -- this worked. I will now need to build out the solution so that the menu pulls data from two additional JSON files and then creates the proper hierarchical structure in the HTML output. Ones step at a time. I am sure I will be posting more questions as I push forward. But again -- thanks for the succinct and effective response.